# How do I reference a bound value in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to edit someone elses code. Is there a way to reference results in the bind in an ActionResult or do I need to pass it explicitly as separate parameter?

```
public ActionResult _SendEmail([Bind(Include = "InvoiceId,EmailMessage,SavedBy,MessageType,Destination,EmailTemplate,SendStatement,Trace,Subject")] SendEmail email)
    {
```

I want to use the value for InvoiceId from the Bind above but cannot seem to reference it directly.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't that a property of your passed parameter email?

Comment: You can just access the `email` variable inside the method.

Comment: Do you mean `email.InvoiceId`?